# Why does not the post method work when the Get method works in RestController?

Tags: spring-boot, postman, spring-restcontroller

My GET method is working fine with Json but I always get an error when I used post method. I used codes that in below.

**RestController**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class AjaxApiRestController {

    private static final String[] province = {
            "Aragon",
            "Catalonia"
    };

    private static final String[][] district =  {
            {"Barbastro","Fraga","Jaca"},
            {"Granollers","Vich","Barcelona"}
    };

    @GetMapping("/ajax/district") //it working!
    public List<String> getDistrict(@RequestBody Province province){
        for(int i=0; i<this.province.length; i++){
            if(this.province[i].equals(province.getProvince())){
                return Arrays.asList(district[i]);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @PostMapping("/ajax/district") //it's not working!
    public List<String> getDistrictPost(@RequestBody Province province){
        for(int i=0; i<this.province.length; i++){
            if(this.province[i].equals(province.getProvince())){
                return Arrays.asList(district[i]);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Province**

```
class Province{

    private String province;

    public String getProvince() {
        return province;
    }

    public void setProvince(String province) {
        this.province = province;
    }
}
```

I use `Postman` to check the `RestController`.

In `GET` method: By sending this command I get the following output.

```
{
    "province":"Catalonia"
}
```

**GET output:**

```
[
    "Granollers",
    "Vich",
    "Barcelona"
]
```

In `POST` method: By sending this command I get the following output.

```
{
    "province":"Catalonia"
}
```

**POST output:**

```
{
"timestamp": "2019-02-25T08:52:10.850+0000",
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"message": "No message available",
"path": "/api/ajax/district"
}
```

As a result, when we examine the codes, the GET method works and the POST method does not work.
Why does not the post method work when the Get method works? Is there error in code that I can't see? Is there anyone who can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are trying to use both (POST, GET) Methods for the same functionality. 
using @RequestBody with a GET method is not a good practice. 
Have you added spring security dependency and configuration?

If yes, then adding method name may help you as below.
.antMatchers(**HttpMethod.POST**,"/yourRequestURL").permitAll()

Comment: I tried your code but it is not working. 

`antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
.authenticated()
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/ajax/district").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
.anyRequest().authenticated()`

Comment: I used these code in the wrong place. Thank you for your interest and your solution.
`@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/ajax/district");
}`

[The other auxiliary resource is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31832148/allow-get-request-but-not-post-request-spring-security/43351607)